# Python Notebook - split Year and Month into 2 different columns

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have 1 column in my python notebook called Date. This contains 2017-05

I need to split this into 2 columns so one called Year and One MonthNo?

Code i have atm;

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

crimes['NewDate'] = crimes['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.split( [0], '%Y-%m'))

crimes['MonthNo'] = crimes['Date'].apply(lambda x: str(x.split()[0].split('-')[0]))

monthDict = {'01' : 'Jan', '02' : 'Feb', '03' : 'Mar', '04' : 'Apr', '05' : 'May', '06' : 'June', '07' : 'Jul', '08' : 'Aug', '09' : 'Sep', '10' : 'Oct', '11' : 'Nov', '12' : 'Dec' }

crimes['Month'] = crimes['MonthNo'].apply(lambda x: monthDict[x])
crimes.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on the hyphen, then use the **calendar** module to get the month name or abbreviation directly.

```
import calendar
import pandas as pd

dates = ['2017-05','2017-04','2016-03']
crimes = pd.DataFrame()

years = [int(i.split('-')[0]) for i in dates]
months = [int(i.split('-')[1]) for i in dates]
month_names = [calendar.month_name[i] for i in months]

#Alternatively, use abbrv for abbreviation
#month_names = [calendar.month_abbr[i] for i in months]

crimes['Year'] = years
crimes['Month'] = month_names
```